# How to show that if $x^T x = 0$, then $x=0$ for any column vector $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces

I did the proof and got it wrong, it'd be really helpful if someone could point me in the right direction or show me how to do it. The $T$ in $(x)^Tx=0$ means transpose; I wasn't sure if that was clear in the title.

Comment: $(x)^Tx$ is a sum of squares of entries of $x$; if any entry were non-zero the sum of squares would be positive

Comment: Another way to see it: ${\bf x}^T{\bf x}$ is the squared length of $\bf x$; if the squared length is $0$, then ${\bf x} = {\bf 0}$.

Comment: Also, $x^Tx$ is simply the scalar product $<x,x> = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2$ which is only zero in the case of $x = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$x=\left(
   \begin{matrix}
    x_1  \\
    x_2 \\
. \\
.\\
.\\
x_n 
        \end{matrix}\
\right).
$$
Then $x^Tx$ = $x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2$.

Since for all real $x_i$, $x_i^2 = 0$ if $x_i=0$ and $x_i^2>0$ otherwise,

$x^Tx=0$ implies $x_i=0$ for all $i$, i.e., $x=\mathbf 0.$